# Table eats away tops of letters - what should I adjust to fix it?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have a table in an MS Word document created by FineReader, an OCR software. I use MS Word 2007. Now some of the words appear clipped at the top, like this:

> [image]

What should I adjust to make the table look normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What should I adjust to make the table look normal?

You need to change the spacing before/after the paragraph and/or the line spacing.

> 1. Select the paragraphs you want to change.
>
>    Tip: If you decide you want to change line spacing for the entire
>      document, and not just specific paragraphs, press Ctrl+A. That
>      combination of keys selects all text in your document.
> 2. Choose Home > Line and Paragraph Spacing.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Choose the number of line spaces you want or choose Line Spacing Options at the bottom of the menu, and then select the options you
>      want in the Paragraph dialog box under Spacing.
>
>    [image: The Spacing options are highlighted in the Paragraph dialog box.]
>
>    If you want to change the spacing before or after the selected
>      paragraphs, in the Before or After box and enter the amount of space
>      that you want.

Source [Change the line spacing in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-line-spacing-in-Word-1970e24a-441c-473d-918f-c6805237fbf4)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that both tops and bottoms are clipped. It happens when line height is set too low. Try to adjust it to 1.

Comment: Can I somehow set it to "self-adjust"?

Comment: 1 is kinda self-adjust. This value is proportional to line height defined by the current font, so 1 means "just use what the font recommends", it's a safe choice.